# Hyper-V on Windows 10, can't add/change hardware

Tags: hyper-v, windows-10

I have Windows 10 build 10586.164 installed on my machine, and am trying to set up a Hyper-V test lab.

I find that after I restart my PC, I can add and change hardware without issue, but after a while, I start getting this kind of error when modifying hardware:
[image]

This seems to also happen when adding disks and things of that nature.

The events I see don't tell me much:
[image]

I have seen some people seeing the same issue with older version of Hyper-V, but their solutions don't work or don't apply.

Has anyone come across this in Windows 10 before and have any idea what may be causing this? Could it be a permissions or group membership thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Turns out our default domain policy had specific users assigned for log on as service.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2779204

I just needed to add the NT Virtual Machine\Virtual Machines group to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably going to get closed due to being a non-server OS, but...

Check your antivirus and see if it's blocking changes.  You might need to create exceptions of some sort for your VMs.

Comment: Yes that one of the suggestions I saw for previous versions, but I am not running any anti-virus outside of Windows Defender